# How to write a Django query where coloum_value < 100?

Tags: django

I have a table like this in DJango?

```
| id | user_id | name          | source         | remaining | start_date                 | time_remaining | size |
+----+---------+---------------+----------------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------+------+
|  1 |       1 | ok.txt        | ngs.pradhi.com |        20 | February 05, 2013, 08:01AM | 1              | 4 MB |
|  2 |       1 | NC_008253.fna | ngs.pradhi.com |        20 | February 05, 2013, 08:02AM | 1              | 4 MB |
|  3 |       1 | test.data     | ngs.pradhi.com |         0 | February 05, 2013, 08:21AM | 1              | 4 MB
```

I want to retrieve the data where `user_id = request.user.id` and `remaining < 100`.
Tried using:

```
Queue.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id, remaining < 100) But didn't work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Queue.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id, remaining__lt=100).exclude(remaining=0)
```

[Django Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#lt)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to show where remaining < 100 and not equals to 0. Thanks